# Difference in Formulas for Expected Payout by Reinsurer

Tags: distributions, expected-value

We're given the random variables $X$ , $Y$ & $Z$ defined as follows :

$X$ : The claim amount received.

$Y$ : The amount paid by the insurer.

$Z$ : The amount paid by the re-insurer.

Let's say the retention limit is $M$. Thus the function $Y$ and $Z$ are defined as follows :

$$ Y = \begin{cases} 
      X, & X<M \\
      M, & X  \geq M \\ 
\end{cases} $$

$$ Z = \begin{cases} 
      0, & X<M \\
      X-M, & X  \geq M \\ 
\end{cases} $$

Now we want to find the amount paid by the re-insurer :

For this , what I do is , I work out $E(Z)$ , which is given by :

$E(Z) = \int_0^{M}(0 )f_X (x) dx + \int_M^{\infty}(X-M)f_X(x)dx$

=> $\int_M^{\infty}(X-M)f_X(x)dx$

My question is , what's the difference between $E(Z|X\geq M)$ and $E(Z)$.

The function $E(Z)$ too gives the expected amount paid by the re-insurer , whereas in the texts I read , it's given by $E(Z|X \geq M)$.

Can anyone explain ?

Answer (score 1):

$E(Z) = P(X < M)E(Z|X < M) + P(X \ge M)E(Z|X \ge M) = P(X \ge M)E(Z|X \ge M)$.

$E(Z)$ is the unconditional expected amount paid by the reinsurer.  $E(X|Z \ge M)$ is the expected amount paid by the reinsurer given that is pays anything, which has probability $P(X \ge M)$ of occurring.